# slope intercept to the general form in computer code?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, data-analysis

I want to make a function that converts a straight line equation from slope intercept to the general form in computer code I already know how to do the opposite :

```
def general2Si(A,B,C):
m=-A/B
b=-C/B
return m,b
```

Comment: What form do you think such an inverse function would take?

Comment: The general form of the straight line $y=mx+c$ is $mx-y+c=0$. So you should return $m,-1,c$.

Comment: A , B ,C should be integer numbers and A should additionally be positive